# How can i do the dynamic .htaccess redirection on multiple directories level

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have multiple cities directories, want to do the 301 internal redirections for many cities.

e.g.
`https://wwww.exampl.com/ciytname/abc/initial_url.html` want to redirect on `https://wwww.exampl.com/cityname/abc/final_url.html`

cityname is variable

my code below not working out.

```
Redirect 301 /*/abc/initial_url.html /*/abc/final.html

Redirect 301 /cityname/abc/initial_url.html /cityname/abc/final.html
```

I can't do for each city

Comment: Hello Rahul, could you please do check provided answers once and let the respective answer know on how it went? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a `RedirectMatch` rule that supports regular expressions like this:

```sh
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+/abc)/initial_url\.html$ /$1/final_url.html
```

Answer (score 1):

For your shown samples, could you please try following.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^ciytname/abc/initial_url.html/?$ cityname/abc/final_url.html [NC,L]
```

---

---

For any generic URIs could you please try following.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/initial_url.html/?$ $1/$2/final_url.html [NC,L]
```